# jquery-ui-map framework not working properly on jqm 1.1.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-map

I have this little snippet running on jquery 1.7.1, jqm 1.1.0 and jquery-ui-maps v3.

Does anybody of you encountered any problem when switching from jqm1.1.0 to 1.1.1?
I had this code on a jqm application instance and it was working before the update:

```
function loadGMaps() {
$(document).live('pageinit', function() {
    $('#main-map').gmap({'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function(map) {           
        var self = this;            
        self.watchPosition( function(position, status) {
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                if ( !self.get('markers').client ) {
                    self.addMarker({ 'id': 'client', 'position': latlng, 'bounds': true });
                } else {
                    self.get('markers').client.setPosition(latlng);
                    map.panTo(latlng);
                }
                /*self.search({ 'address': 'Vancouver, Canada' }, function(results, status) {               
                    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                        console.log(results[0]);
                        }
                    });*/
            }
        });         
    }});
}); 

$(document).live( 'pageshow', function() {
    $('#main-map').gmap('refresh')
});

$(document).live( 'pagehide', function() {
    $('#main-map').gmap('clearWatch')
});
}
```

Using the ff debugger, it seems not to call the self.watchPosition() command, just skips it.

The code is taken from here
http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#gps_map

Could anybody give me a piece of advice there?
Thanks!

EDIT: The HTML code I used is pretty similar to the one in the example:

```
<div id='intro' data-role='content'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='twelvecol last'>
      <div class='cell'>
        <div id='main-map' style='height:300px;' class='align-center'>
          <h5>
            <span>Map</span>
          </h5>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: We need some html to reproduce the problem

Comment: If you can fill in the missing bits at http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/bqFtg/1/ Then I will show you how to track down this problem

Answer (score 0):

This apparently seems to be a reported bug!

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/issues/detail?id=63

Did you log this?

Will still try to figure out a work around...

hth.

Comment: Yes, I did report that to check in with them as well... let's see if they have a solution...